# Indesign - remove empty cells from table

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript

I have imported XML which contains nested tables and have created a script to remove all empty cells which is as:

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
for(var i=myDocument.textFrames.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    for(var j=myDocument.textFrames[i].tables.length-1; j>=0; j--){
        for(var k=myDocument.textFrames[i].tables[j].rows.length-1; k>=0; k--){
            myContents = 0;
            for(var l=myDocument.textFrames[i].tables[j].rows[k].cells.length-1; l>=0; l--){
                if (myDocument.textFrames[i].tables[j].rows[k].cells[l].contents != "") myContents++;  
                }
                    if (myContents == 0) myDocument.textFrames[i].tables[j].rows[k].remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

This works for an ordinary table, but on my XML document which contains the tables it doesnt remove the empty cells even though it hits the right if statement

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Your script works for me, on natively created tables *and* on XML-imported ones. So ... are you 100% sure that there are **no** characters at all in those supposedly-empty rows? No spaces? No empty XML markers?

Comment: The XML for the empty cells are as such : <Cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="200" aid:pstyle="paraSynonym_Title"  aid5:cellstyle="cellSynonym_Title"></Cell>

Comment: so there isnt anything in the cell

Comment: Not in the XML, I meant in your InDesign file. That's where your script finds "something" – anything – that makes a cell 'not empty'.

Comment: Does it work for you if its a table within a table?

Comment: I did not try that; first time you mention it. Is that the one and only problematic case? According to the logic of your script, they would not be processed; it needs yet another loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the empty rows that are not found by the script are those that are in a table nested in its entirety inside a larger table.

The script logic does not see them; it only looks at tables 'immediately' inside text frames. To fix this, it needs a separate loop inside the Table loop that specifically checks for nested tables. (Which does not scale well – if there may be tables inside these tables inside tables, it needs *another* loop. It is better to write a separate *function*, which can call itself recursively; then it works with tables-in-tables-in-tables-in ...)

An additional minor improvement is to not loop over *text frames*, but instead over entire *stories*. (Which, apart from speed, also has the advantage that tables in overset text also get processed.)

All in all, the following complete script should work for nested tables:

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
for(var i=0; i<myDocument.stories.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<myDocument.stories[i].tables.length; j++)
    {
        processTable(myDocument.stories[i].tables[j]);
    }
}

function processTable (any_table)
{
    var r,c,t, isEmpty;

    for (r=any_table.rows.length-1; r>=0; r--)
    {
        isEmpty = true;
        for (c=0; c< any_table.rows[r].cells.length; c++)
        {
            for (t=0; t<any_table.rows[r].cells[c].tables.length; t++)
                processTable (any_table.rows[r].cells[c].tables[t]);

            if (any_table.rows[r].cells[c].contents != '')
                isEmpty = false;
        }
        if (isEmpty)
            any_table.rows[r].remove();
    }
}
```